# Как перезагрузить slick slider после изменений в блоке

Tags: javascript, slick.js

Есть набор блоков к которым подключен популярный слайдер slick slider, но на сайте в зависмости от ситуации нужно удалять некоторые или прибавлять, как в таком случае заново сделать чтобы этот слайдер записал клоны и работал с измененным контентом? $('.slides').slick('reinit'); $('.slides').slick('unslick'); с последующим обьявлением $('.slides').slick() не работают(

Comment: ну или можно к прмеру не удалять а скрывать если так будет способ

Comment: добавьте свой код я постараюсь помочь

Comment: Значит сам вызов вот такой - 
$('.slides').slick({
  slidesToShow: 1,
  slidesToScroll: 1,
  autoplay: true,
  autoplaySpeed: 1500,
  arrows: false,
  dots: true,
  dotsClass: 'slick-dots-2',
  asNavFor: '.menu-desc'
 });

потом иногда некоторые блоки удаляются или добавляются другие и слайдер начинает глючить

Comment: На англоязычном overflowe нашёл это - $('#slick-slider').slick('refresh');

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте взят инициализацию в переменную.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var slider = $('.your-class').slick({
    // todo
  });
  slider.slick('reinit');
});
```

Comment: нет к сожалению( он добавляет поверх существующих и получается каша из кнопок

Answer (score 0):

оказывается есть такая возможность в самом слайдере, можно сделать unslick потом поменять все что нужно затем еще раз вызвать slick или можно сделать как я недавно нашел на одном сайте .slick('slickAdd','element') ну или slickRemove вместо slickAdd но второй способ я еще не проверял